# Avoiding global context in jQuery used on all pages of a CMS

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, global, encapsulation

I work with a proprietary CMS every day, and one of the easiest ways to customize individual sites is with the theme.js that is present on all pages. The preferred approach is usually jQuery, but vanilla javascript is also encouraged. In a sense, think of it as being like the functions file in Wordpress. It's not a perfect solution, and more it just tacked on to do new things, but it's what it is.

When I add isolated functions, things that aren't called but just act when the page loads, I want to add them in a way that's more standards compliant and less prone to bugs. One thing I want to avoid is blatant global context(s).

Example of how I was shown to do it at first:

```
$(function() {

    $('div.target').append('<p>New stuff</p>');

});
```

We talked it over, and it was agreed to encapsulate:

```
(function() {
    var foo;
    if (bar) {
        // some code
    }
}());
```

Problem is, when I run the code exactly like that, it doesn't take effect.
So, I changed it to this:

```
(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('div.target').append('<p>New stuff</p>');

    });

}(jQuery));
```

That works, but I don't want it to defeat the purpose. Is adding `$(document).ready(function()` back peddling our endeavor to encapsulate and avoid global context with small functions?

Comment: If you don't want to `document.ready`, move your code at the end of the page right before the closing `</body>` tag. But honestly, I just don't understand your question, what you are trying to achieve and why you changed from the first one to the second one when they're not doing the same thing.

Comment: The code in your (first) `document.ready()` *does not* pollute the global context. It's inside a function, just like your other tries.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - I cannot move the theme.js file call in the pages. That is part of the CMS. It's dynamically generated. I can only add and remove code within that file.

Comment: @haim770 Thank you for the clarification. I was told my first example was polluting the global context. I was under the impression it was not, but I was told by most of the back end engineering staff recently that it was and to do it the second way.

Comment: Your second code snippet is not a `document.ready()` equivalent anyway. The third is only providing a way to make sure `$` is indeed `jQuery` (in case of possible conflict).

Comment: @haim770 - If a conflict is remotely possible, would using the last example in my post therefore be the safest bet?

Comment: Yes, that is the common approach.

Comment: You second example is a way to make a closure (preventing jQuery conflict and making variable local instead of global). It allow you to pass unlimited amount of external (global) variable which will not be affected anymore (if the global variable change the local one will not). The second one also make a closure (variable declared in the function are inaccessible outside that function) but you can't pass any arguments. That function is a document ready handler.

Comment: That would be a safe way to do it. You can also look to use jQuery.noConflict(); http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Thanks for the additional info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(function() {` is just a shortcut to `$(document).ready(function() {`.
In both cases you are inside a function, so as long as you use the `var` when assigning variables they won't pollute the global scope.

Note that you can use multiple `ready` handlers with no problem.

Comment: Would it therefore be safe to use:
`(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {
    
        $target.append('<p>New Text</p>');
    
    });

}(jQuery));`

or would something like

`(function( $ ) {
    
    var doSomeStuff = function() {
        var $target = $('div.target');

        if ( $target.get(0) ) {
            $target.append('<p>New Text</p>');
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        doSomeStuff();
    });

}( jQuery ));`

Be better? Or would the latter be overkill?

Comment: Apologies. I didn't realize code in the comments would be forced to one line. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/hfmnnzaz/